# QTP - getting value of element

Tags: automated-tests, qtp

I am beginning with QTP and just cannot find out how to get value of element. For example when I just want to compare the number of results found by google. I tried to select the element with object spy and use Val(Element) to assign the value into variable..but it doesnt work. Could anyone help with this? BTW, I am not sure whether selecting the text (element) to compare with Object spy is correct.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `GetROProperty` in order to get the text and then parse it for the value.

Looking at a Google results page I see that the result is in a paragraph with `id=resultStats` in the 3rd bold tag.

```
 <p id="resultStats"> Results <b>1</b> - <b>10</b> of about 
    <b>2,920,000</b> 
 for <b>qtp</b>. (<b>0.22</b> seconds)</p>
```

So the following script gets the number (as a string with commas).

```
Browser("micclass:=Browser")
 .Page("micclass:=Page")
  .WebElement("html id:=resultStats")
   .WebElement("html tag:=b","index:=2").GetROProperty("innertext")
```

Comment: Thank you, is there any way how to find out the element ID from QTP instead of reading the source? ObjectSpy shows only "Webelement"

Comment: @Tomas, yes it should appear as `html id` in the object spy